# Unable to catch logs of a post request to a service

Tags: laravel, vue.js, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am making an axios post request to a service and in the xml response from the server, I'm getting a `resCode:1008` and response message of `system error: please retry`, however, from the service, I am unable to see the error logs of the request to the service.

Comment: To help you better, I first need to know what error code 1008 indicates in the service documentation for which you are requesting it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks guys, the issue was from the service I was trying to call. I've been able to resolve it.